# How to run JS code after form Iframe loaded and place custom value in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, iframe

http://dev.uniteconferencing.com/conference-account-sign-free/?pcode=25u50PT
I am trying to get pcode value from url and place into IFRAME form i get the value with this code

```
jQuery(function(){
      var pcode = location.href;
      var pcode = pcode.split('=');
      var pcode = pcode[pcode.length - 1];
      console.log(pcode);

});
```

but when i try to place this value in form promo code field here http://prntscr.com/dftezo i am unable to place this value because this form loads after every thing loads. I tried my best using **on load**, **bind** but still not completed. please help. i am stuck in it from 2 days. Thanks

Comment: Does your code run within the code on:
http://dev.uniteconferencing.com/conference-account-sign-free/?pcode=25u50PT ? If so, getting the pcode value is simple, but not sure that's what you want.

Comment: Can you share the code for the iframe too?

Comment: form is loading on this page http://dev.uniteconferencing.com/conference-account-sign-free/?pcode=25u50PT . this is showing via shortcode. its a wordpress website.

Comment: Are you able to get `pcode` correctly from your code above?

Comment: yes 100%. but unable to place in form field

Comment: Can you share the code you've tried for adding to the form field?

Comment: http://www.captainform.com/docs/ this is wordpress plugin i used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129853/discussion-between-muddasir-abbas-and-jonmrich).

Comment: Just FYI, it's not particularly good form on here to request help from other people's answers pointing them to your own question... but still.. in this instance, it looks like your problem isn't anything to do with the javascript, I think it's the same-domain policy, since your host page is uniteconferencing.com but the iframe is to captainform.com, which means you can't edit the iframed content since it isn't from the same domain

Comment: Thanks its fixed.